# How do I interpret the specs of a weather balloon?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, radiosounding

I'm planning a high-altitude weather balloon project (to around 100000 feet, or 30 km) some time down the line to take video and pictures of near space altitudes and I have some questions I need to ask before doing so:

1. What does the weight of a weather balloon mean such as 150 g, 500 g, 2000 g, etc mean?
2. What diameter of weather balloon do I need? I'm planning to take upto around 1-2 kg of payload consisting of cameras, Arduino, Raspberry Pi, GPS, parachute etc.

Comment: You may get some information here, but these questions are likely to be best answered by the balloon manufacturer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The weight of a balloon determines most of its specifications, though I'm not sure if they are generalized or specific to a manufacturer.  Looking at [one supplier](http://kaymontballoons.com/Weather_Forecasting.html) we can get a feel for what you need.  For a 1 kg payload it looks like you'd want a minimum of a 1200g balloon.  According to the site linked, this 1200g balloon will have:

- 6.0 ft diameter at launch
- 113 ft$^3$ volume at release
- 320 fpm ascent rate
- 28 ft diameter at burst
- 109,000 ft altitude at burst
- 1190 g free lift

If you need 2kg of payload you'd need to size a bigger balloon.  In general your application is not different from the specs of a normal upper-air sounding launch, so you should be able to spec your balloons directly from suppliers of sounding balloons.  All of the balloons for a 1-2 kg payload should burst above 100,000 feet so it just a matter of picking a supplier and a balloon sized for your payload (per the manufacturer specifications).

Comment: what a pleasant surprise to see another one of Aviation SE out here! Thanks for the answer! BTW, in this instructable, it appears a 600g balloon was good enough to get p. high with roughly the same payload: http://www.instructables.com/id/My-Space-Balloon-Project-Stratohab-Success-High/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Furthermore, the site seems to say it's OK to go for 600g to get to ~FL 750-900. http://kaymontballoons.com/Near_Space_Photography.html

Comment: And I'm getting a really good deal from an Indian supplier, PAWAN EXPORTS selling 2 600g balloons for Rs 3000 or $60,  so I guess I'll go on that route :)

Comment: @shortstheory good to know.  A 600g balloon will use less than half the helium of a 1200g balloon and be a more manageable launch.

Comment: @shortstheory Good luck and it would be great if you post a comment with a blog/webpage link to the details of your balloon mission - i.e. photos, videos, measurements etc. would be nice to see. Also, if you get any more details/specs from the manufacturer, please post them as an answer here.

Comment: Thank you @IRO-bot. I'm a bit busy with high school till June 2015, but our balloon mission will take place shortly after that complete with all the documentation you would want to see!

Comment: @casey does a 600g weather balloon mean it can carry a 600g payload?

Comment: @shortstheory No, that is the weight of the balloon